# How to list products by vendor id in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a meta_query to list all the products of a particular vendor but I do not know how to mount this query.
I am using the WC Vendor plugin.

Comment: Have you looking for this? https://www.skyverge.com/blog/sort-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

Comment: @KayoBruno How your vendors are set in your products, as a category, a tag or a custom field? Without that information nobody can help you. You should give at least the minimal details about it…

Comment: I use the WC Vendor plugin to do this.

Comment: As I don't use this plugin, can you check in your database for one related product ID in **wp_postmeta** table, which 'meta_key' is (or are) used by this plugin (Or which are the categories or attributes used to set this on the product)… Without this information I can't help